# ListAdapter in Android guide to populating list views. What does it mean?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to learn how to make an app using Xamarin and C#. I want to populate a ListView with data from a database and I tried to reference  official sources. But I came across this piece of code

```
   [Activity(Label = "BasicTable", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
   public class HomeScreen : ListActivity {
   string[] items;
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       items = new string[] { "Vegetables","Fruits","Flower Buds","Legumes","Bulbs","Tubers" };
       ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
   }
   protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
}
```

I have no clue what is the function of the line with ListAdapter. My xamarin is throwing an exeption telling me that "ListAdapter" does not exist in current context. I was trying my best to understand what this is and so far I know that this should be an Interface from BaseAdapter but I don't know how to fix the code to make it work. I would be much happier with an explanation as to what this construction is and what it is supposed to do and not in "fixed code".

Comment: `ListActivity` is just an activity that displays a list of items by binding to a data source such as an array, and exposes event handlers when the user selects an item. You bind the `ListActivity`'s `ListView` object to data using a class that implements the `ListAdapter` interface. More here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: I wish I could mark your comment as an awnser. It helped me a lot in troubleshooting my problems.

Comment: I can add it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListActivity` is just an activity that displays a list of items by binding to a data source such as an array, and exposes event handlers when the user selects an item. You bind the `ListActivity's` `ListView` object to data using a class that implements the `ListAdapter` interface.

[More info here](http://%20developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "ListAdapter" to "this.ListAdapter" since it's being inherited from ListActivity.

Comment: I encountered this issue in the Phoneword Multiscreen tutorial app.  I missed that it inherits from ListActivity rather than just Activity.  This helped me solve it.  Thx!